# $SU(2)$ representation that conserves the Lie algebra

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, rotations

I've seen that there are many representations of $SU(2)$ on $\mathbb R^3$, one of these representation is the map from $SU(2)$ to the set of matrices of $SO(3)$. This representation conserves the Lie algebra of SU(2) (I mean that the imagine of the map is a group with the same Lie algebra of the domain). My question is, are there other representations of $SU(2)$ on $\mathbb R^3$ which image is a group with the same Lie algebra of $SU(2)$?

Comment: I don't see that the identity representation has as image a group with the same Lie algebra of $SU(2)$. Can you tell me why the Lie algebra should the same?

Comment: I think this answer is no :

* such a reprensentation would give a SU(2) --> GL(3,R) because the action is linear.

* but because SU(2) is compact and connected, the image will actuall fall in SO(3) (up to conjugation) which is the maximal compact connected subgroup of GL(3).

* But because SO(3,R) is simple, there is no (finite) normal subgroup, so none of its quotient is a group.

Comment: But the map of $SU(2)$ is not a representation on $\mathbb R^3$ right?

Comment: thanks for the observation but my concern is only on $\mathbb R^3$. Do you think it's unique in this case?

Comment: SU(2) and SO(3) are not isomorphic

Comment: Unique up to equivalence of representations?